# Nashorn JJS: set heap size on command line

Tags: jvm, nashorn, jjs

Using the JJS tool for Nashorn+ JVM, how do we set JVM arguments?

I tried this:

jjs  -Xmx512m test.js

but got this:

> "-Xmx512m" is not a recognized option. Use "-h" or "-help" to see a
>   list of all supported options.

Sepcifically I want to set the following

-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m
-Xmx512m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For JJS use -J before jvm args:

-J-Xmx512m
-J-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m